# Why are these barplots on top of each other?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm trying to create subplots using matplotlib where there are 2 rows and 3 columns. I have a dataframe `df` with columns `A` thru `F`. I want each of the subplots to be a bar graph of each column `A` thru `F`.

I'm sure it's just a small mistake in the code but how do I get these to plot in different subplots and not all on top of each other?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4,15,size=(100, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df['A'].value_counts()

rows, cols = 2,3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

myplots = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

for j in myplots:
    x = range(len(df[j].value_counts()))
    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(3):
            ax[row, col].bar(x, df[j].value_counts().sort_index())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to plot the value counts for each column in separate subplots:

```
(df.stack().groupby(level=1)
     .value_counts()
     .unstack(level=0)
     .plot.bar(layout=(2,3), subplots=True));
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Note:** to answer your question *why ...*:

```
for j in myplots:
    x = range(len(df[j].value_counts()))
    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(3):
```

Since the `j` loop is outer-most, you effectively draw  on 
value counts of each column (`df[j]`) on every subplot. That's why the subplots look identical.

To make your solution work, use `zip`:

```
rows, cols = 2,3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

myplots = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

for j, ax in zip(myplots, axes.ravel()):
    df[j].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Correct, and I'd like to actually use the for-loop. Do you think there's a way to make my code work above?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (In my opinion, it was mistake in index solving)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4,15,size=(100, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF')).  #  (100,6)
df['A'].value_counts()

rows, cols = 2,3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

myplots = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

#for j in myplots:
    #x = range(len(df[j].value_counts()))
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(3):
        ind = row*3+col  # here it is
        # ax[row, col].bar(list(range(len(df['A']))), df[myplots[ind]])

        set_of_values = df[myplots[ind]].value_counts()
        count_of_values = df[myplots[ind]].value_counts().sort_index()        
        ax[row, col].bar(set_of_values, count_of_values)

        ax[row,col].set_xlabel(myplots[ind])
```

[image]

Comment: What happened to the `value_counts()` portion of the code though? When I tried your code for my data it just plots all the raw data.

Comment: Pay attention, i have changed dimension of matrix in dataframe (5th line of code) from (100,6) to (10,6) to make plots more readable. May be it's the reason

Comment: That's not it. The original dataframe is meant to be 100+ rows long. What needs to be plotted in the end is: `df[j].value_counts().sort_index()` returns a series of unique values rather than the raw data.

Comment: Your subplots look good but I don't think it's actually plotting what I want.

Comment: i have made update. Now it count and plot unique values